# how to view a revision of a file with bazaar?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I want to view a revision of a file without having to revert my repository to the said revision.

Is this possible via the command line?

> note: I know that `bzr log <my file> -p` let me view the changes and the diff. But this is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is probably `bzr cat`. To specify a revision, use the `-r` option:

```
bzr cat -r <revision> <file>
```